# HTML/HTML5 website creating using Jodd(java) framework

Tags: java, jodd

I've been reading about Jodd(java) framework and it looks interesting to me. But I see that it seems to be jsp/servlet based. Can you develop strictly html/html5 dynamic website without jsps with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. As you can see, in Jodd Madvoc you have this concept of `Result` : each (java) action returns it. Results are the one that defines how you are going to render the page. By default, there are JSP results, as this is a standard, right; but nothing stops you to simply have a i.e. Freemarker result or to use any other template engine. People are doing this often. Moreover, `Results` are made to be configured. See: http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/results.html

`Result` does not need only to return HTML content. There is a `JsonResult` for example, or `RawResult` that can return a JSON or any string.

If you want REST-ish interface that only results with JSONs, you can do that as well, checkout: http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/rest.html

Madvoc should be configurable enough to fit your needs. Just don't think of it as a 'solution-in-a-box', but a real framework, that you need to dig just a little, but you will find what you need :)

Comment: this is very usefull indeed. Will check it out as soon as I can. Just out of curiousity, are you using Jodd by any chance currently or at any point of time.

Comment: Sure, I was using the whole stack; depending on project needs.

Comment: It would be super awesome if you could create a youtube "Jodd getting started"fvideo. Would you condiser it?

Comment: @Vuzi yes! Actually, we do plan 2 things: a) videos and tutorials b) some tool for easy project template generation.

Comment: @ игор Awesome!!!! Keep up the good work guys!!!! Really believe in your framework or should I say ours

Comment: @Vuzi thanx very much, we will do our best

Answer (score 0):

You can develop strictly html/html5 dynamic Websites without JSPs for sure, there are many ways to do it, but in my personal opinion, I believe that you can use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) for your front-end development (HTML5/CSS3). This framework will allow you to implement all your client side without minor issues. It is based on HTML5, so no JSP files will be required. If you are used to MVC or MVVM, well this framework will allow you to work with any of these two approaches.

Dynamic Web Application? Need to show data from a database or store records? No problem, Angular supports AJAX calls to REST Web Services which you can implement with the programming language you feel more comfortable. If it is Java, then you can go for some REST Web Services using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

Hope this information is useful for you.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you, I was specifically asking if this could be done using the **Jodd(java) framework**.